# WSO2 EI - Error while posting JSON request with special characters to API

Tags: api, special-characters, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm trying to post a JSON request to an API created in WSO2 EI.
The purpose of the API is to grab the request and post it to an Amazon SQS.

The JSON request is having \r\n, @ characters which is causing it not to get submitted to a SQS queue.

As it is an integration tool, I strongly believe there should be something wrong in the way we are using it for request processing.

Any quick help is highly appreciated.

Comment: json has \r\n, {attr: "my value"\r\n}, or json value has \r\n which makes json invalid {attr: "my \r\n value"} ? Log json and test in here https://www.jslint.com/.

Comment: better log it into file (split sequence and use file transport). SInce it is tricky if u copy paste it from console how \r\n are treated by text buffer.

Comment: Thank you for the response Simar.